# how to check condition php file input image array value is empty or not empty

Tags: php

Array name value is empty but print else condition. how to solve this.

this is my html file input code for image.

```
<input id="editimagefile" name="editimagefile[]" type="file" multiple=true>
```

this is my php value assigned code

```
$imgsfiles = $_FILES['editimagefile']['name'];

if(empty($imgsfiles))
{
    echo "empty";
}
else
{
    echo "value assigned";
}
```

Comment: first check `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: i checked alredy print_r($_FILES) but else part are executed....

Comment: than use trim maybe some extra space here `if(empty(trim($imgsfiles)))`

Comment: So post the result of `print_r($_FILES)`.

Comment: trim function also use but same else function are executed

Comment: its better to share the result or print_r($_FILES)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `name="editimagefile[]"`is array field thus `$_FILES['editimagefile']['name']` is an array too. Count function will return greater then 0 and it is not empty array but contains empty element.

So if you are sure you have more then one element you can use following:

```
if(in_array("", $_FILES['editimagefile']['name'])){
      echo 'contains empty elements';
}else{
      echo 'correct';
}
```

if only one element then you can use following:

```
if (empty($_FILES['editimagefile']['name'][0])) { 
    echo 'contains empty elements';
}else{
    echo 'correct';
}
```

Comment: @jeroen if there are X file fields then count($_FILES['editimagefile']['name']) will return X no matter file selected or not